# Erro em algoritmo Visualg - Cálculo de média simples e classificação - Iniciante

Tags: algoritmo, visualg

sou iniciante e estou aprendendo algoritmos.

Comecei a fazer um algoritmo pra cálculo de média simples e também uma classificação com base na média, mas o visualg acusa uma série de erros na sintaxe que não consigo identificar.

Caso alguém consiga me ajudar ficaria muito grato

Obrigado desde já e peço perdão caso seja muito elementar, sou bem iniciante.

Segue abaixo o algoritmo:

```
'algoritmo "Media"
var

n1, n2, m: real
clf : caractere

// O objetivo é calcular a média simples das notas e fazer uma classificação


inicio

EscrevaL ("---------------------------")
EscrevaL ("")
EscrevaL ("")
EscrevaL ("     ESCOLA DO JUBERNAL")
EscrevaL ("")
EscrevaL ("")
EscrevaL ("---------------------------")
EscrevaL ("")
EscrevaL ("Seja bem vindo")
EscrevaL ("Escreva a primeira nota: ")
Leia (n1)
EscrevaL ("Escreva a segunda nota: ")
Leia (n2)
m <- (n1 + n2) / 2
EscrevaL ("SUA MÉDIA DAS NOTAS É:", m, " !")

se (m >= 9) e (m <=10) entao
   clf <- A
senao
   se (m >= 7) e (m < 9) entao
      clf <- B
   senao
      se (m >= 5) e (m < 7) entao
         clf <- C
      senao
         se (m >= 3) e (m < 5) entao
            clf <- D
         senao
            se (m >= 1) e (m < 3) entao
               clf <- Ê
            senao
               clf <- F
            fimse
         fimse
      fimse
   fimse
fimse


EscrevaL ("-------------------------------------")
EscrevaL ("")
EscrevaL ("           SITUAÇÃO FINAL ")
EscrevaL ("")
EscrevaL ("-------------------------------------")
EscrevaL ("")
EscrevaL ("")
EscrevaL ("SUA MÉDIA DAS NOTAS É:", m, " !")
EscrevaL ("APROVEITAMENTO DO ALUNO:", clf, " !")
se (clf = a ou b ou c) entao
   EscrevaL ("SITUAÇÃO: APROVADO!")
senao
   EscrevaL ("SITUAÇÃO: REPROVADO!")
Fimse
EscrevaL ("")
EscrevaL ("")
EscrevaL ("-------------------------------------")


fimalgoritmo'
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá, Carlos!

Bom, seremos dois iniciando então, porque você é a primeira pessoa que eu respondo aqui! :)

Vamos ver se consigo lhe ajudar.

Bom, em primeiro lugar, ao atribuir valores caractere no VisualG (e na maioria das principais linguagens de programação), precisamos colocar esses valores sempre entre aspas. Então, a sintaxe correta para as partes correspondentes à essa situação é:

```
clf <- "A"
```

O outro erro que encontrei foi na parte que se refere aos testes lógicos compostos. Acredito que foi apenas um lapso seu ao escrever essa parte do código, afinal de contas em um trecho anterior você já havia escrito corretamente. A sintaxe correta referente à esse trecho do código é:

```
se (clf = "A") ou  (clf = "B") ou (clf = "C") entao
```

Repare que eu já tomei a liberdade de corrigir as atribuições de caracteres com as respectivas aspas.

Faça essas duas correções no código e verifique se os erros foram corrigidos aí no seu compilador. Aqui no meu funcionaram perfeitamente!

Bons estudos!

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!